# Table not populating properly from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I want to populate my table with values from array of objects:

This is my code:

```js
let data = [
  {cat: 'one', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'two', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'three', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'four',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'five',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'six',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'seven',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'eight',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'nine',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  
]

let heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
heads.forEach(d => $(`#headers`).append(`<td>${d}</td>`));

data.forEach(td => {
  $(`#body_deets`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
      heads.forEach(th => {
          $(`#body_deets > tr`).append(`<td>${td[th]}</td>`);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='table' border=1>
  <thead><tr id='headers'></tr></thead>
    <tbody id='body_deets'></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, when I try and append data inside the table, it is all adding all the data to one row instead of appending the row one by one. Why is my table not populating properly?

Comment: Hi , change $(`#body_deets > tr`) to $(`#body_deets > tr:last`) see what happens.

Comment: @Swati, works! if you add it as an answer, I can check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code shows that behaviour because you are targetting all `trs` inside your tbody so its appending datas inside all trs . So , to make this work use `:last` this will refer to last tr which is appended to `tbody` . i.e :

```
$(`#body_deets > tr:last`).append(`<td>${td[th]}</td>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that if you keep a reference to the new row, you can add cells to it more easily.

By changing

```
$('#body_deets').append(`<tr></tr>`);
```

to

```
var row = $("<tr>").appendTo("#body_deets");
```

you can then use the new `row` directly without having to find it for each column.

```js
let data = [
  {cat: 'one', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'two', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'three', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'four',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'five',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'six',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'seven',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'eight',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'nine',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  
]

let heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
heads.forEach(d => $('#headers').append(`<th>${d}</th>`));

data.forEach(td => {
  var row = $("<tr>").appendTo('#body_deets');
  heads.forEach(th => {
    row.append(`<td>${td[th]}</td>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='table' border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr id='headers'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='body_deets'></tbody>
</table>
```

This makes your code much easier to follow and quite a bit more efficient - more efficient would be to generate the whole row as a string in one go and then append that.